# C++ initializing a class member object

Tags: c++

I am new to C++, but have some experience in Java.
I would do this in Java:

```
public Class SymbolTable{
   private DynHashtable<String> hst;
   public SymbolTable(){
      hst = new DynHashtable<String>();
   }
}
```

But I don't know how I can do that in C++, should I keep a pointer to DynHashtable or should I keep an Object of it, or there is no difference??

Comment: What is `DynHashtable`?

Comment: It depends. If you have a pointer to an instance of the class, you can control its lifetime. If you have an instance of the class as a member of another class, then the lifetime of that instance is the same as the lifetime of the encapsulating class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case, I guess you don't need to keep any pointer. Give your data member *automatic storage duration*. It will be constructed when the `SymbolTable` object that contains it is constructed, and destructed when the `SymbolTable` object is destructed.

In other word, `SymbolTable` entirely encapsulates and owns the `DynHashtable<string>` object, having the exclusive responsibility of controlling its lifetime.

Also, in C++ you should use `std::string` for representing strings (you must include the `<string>` standard header to import its definition:

```
#include <string>

class SymbolTable {
private:
    DynHashtable<std::string> hst;

public:
    SymbolTable() {
        // ...
    }
};
```

**UPDATE:**

From the comments, it seems that `DynHastable` is not default-constructible, and its constructor accepts an `int` as its parameter. In this case, you have to construct your object in the constructor's initialization list:

```
class SymbolTable {
private:
    DynHashtable<std::string> hst;

public:
    SymbolTable() : hst(42) {
    //            ^^^^^^^^^
        // ...
    }
};
```

Comment: thanks for the reply, but this does not work. Perhaps because I have only a constructor like this: DynHashtable<T>(int);

Comment: @nomnom: What do you mean by "does not work"? Compiler error? If so, what's the message? Runtime error? If so, what's the line where it occurs?

Comment: @nomnom: OK, if the constructor of `DynHastable` accepts an `int`, then you have to construct it in the constructor's initialization list - I will show that in a moment. However, notice that in your question you are doing: `hst = new DynHashtable<String>();` (no argument passed to the constructor)

Comment: Wow, that works!! Thank you so much and sorry I forgot to pass an Integer as parameter to the constructor ^^

Answer (score 1):

In C++ you usually embed the variable directly for value-semantics or you use a `std::shared_ptr` for reference-semantics. Here's value-semantics:

```
#include <string>
#include <unordered_set> // the equivalent of DynHashtable AFAICT

class SymbolTable
{
private:
    std::unordered_set<std::string> hst;
public:
    SymbolTable() // automatically calls the default ctor for hst
    {
    }
};
```

and here's reference-semantics:

```
#include <string>
#include <unordered_set> // the equivalent of DynHashtable AFAICT
#include <memory>        // for std::shared_ptr / std::make_shared

class SymbolTable
{
private:
    std::shared_ptr<std::unordered_set<std::string>> hst;
public:
    SymbolTable()
      : hst(std::make_shared<std::unordered_set<std::string>>())
    {
    }
};
```

but you usually need to define more methods like a copy-ctor, assignment operators, etc.